# LibreOffice 5.1 black text issue within dialogs

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I can't for the life of my find a solution to this problem myself.

After recently installing Ubuntu 16.04 from scratch, I noticed that the bundled LibreOffice (I forget what particular version) had some weird issue with the font in some areas of the UI, being replaced with black squares like in this example:

[Example from version 5.1.3.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y44Hl.png)

I then decided to enable a PPA (https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-5-1), in order to get a more recent version of LibreOffice and see if that would alleviate the problem. But nothing changed, and I can't seem to find anyone with this particular problem either. Perhaps it has something to do with my specs?

CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

GPU: Radeon R9 280X

GPU driver: radeonsi - recent/updated drivers via enabled Padoka PPA (DRM 2.45.0 / LLVM 3.9.0)

Kernel: Currently 4.7 RC2, but same result with Ubuntu 16.04 default kernel

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Have you tried updating the kernel? I recently installed 16.04 minimal with Openbox + xdm, had a ton of problems with freezing, touchpad, xserver, and more! I updated my kernel to 4.5 and it fixed everything. Now it's flawless (so far!) http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/03/upgrade-linux-kernel-4-5-ubuntu/

Comment: What happens with `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk libreoffice --writer`? That code forces LibreOffice to open in gtk2 mode rather than the default gtk3 mode.

Comment: @DKBose No change, but when executing that command, I noticed the following output: `(soffice:20464): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large`

Comment: @PSmith I tried 4.5 and am currently running 4.7 RC2, no change unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this Launchpad bug for details.
[Corrupted Fonts with AMD GPU BUG](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1575000)

Suffice to say according to the chatter in that bug-thread; that you can fix it by purging your current LibreOffice and installing the prerelease 5.2.0
[LibreOffice 5.2](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=deb-x86_64&version=5.2.0&lang=en-US)

Alternatively you can wait for Ubuntu to release "xorg-server 1.18.4" on their repo. It is earmarked for Yakkety Yak (Ubuntu 16.10) and will be backported to 16.04.